# Trying to combine "OR" and "And" statements together in SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, parameters

I am having problems combining or/and statements in SSRS. I am using a couple parameter fields but am not having any luck. Except for the begin and end date I have multiselect choices for the other parameters using queries in the datasets.  My problem is getting all benefits, deductions and pay codes and then limit them to a date range.  The date is not getting filtered.

```
SELECT
  UPR30100.EMPLOYID
  ,UPR30100.CHEKDATE AS [UPR30100 CHEKDATE]
  ,UPR30100.CHEKNMBR
  ,UPR30100.PYADNMBR
  ,UPR30300.PYRLRTYP
  ,UPR30300.PAYROLCD
  ,UPR30300.CHEKDATE AS [UPR30300 CHEKDATE]
  ,UPR30300.UNTSTOPY
  ,UPR30300.PAYRATE
  ,UPR30300.UPRTRXAM
  ,UPR00100.LASTNAME
  ,UPR00100.FRSTNAME
  ,UPR00100.ADRSCODE
  ,UPR00100.BRTHDATE
  ,UPR00100.SOCSCNUM
  ,UPR00100.STRTDATE
  ,UPR00100.BENADJDATE
  ,UPR00100.LASTDAYWORKED_I
  ,UPR30100.VOIDED
  ,UPR30300.DAYSWRDK
  ,SY01200.INET1
  ,UPR00102.ADDRESS1
  ,UPR00102.ADDRESS2
  ,UPR00102.CITY
  ,UPR00102.[STATE]
  ,UPR00102.ZIPCODE
FROM
  UPR30100
  INNER JOIN UPR30300
    ON UPR30100.CHEKNMBR = UPR30300.CHEKNMBR
  INNER JOIN UPR00100
    ON UPR30100.EMPLOYID = UPR00100.EMPLOYID
  INNER JOIN UPR00102
    ON UPR00100.ADRSCODE = UPR00102.ADRSCODE AND UPR00100.EMPLOYID = UPR00102.EMPLOYID
  INNER JOIN SY01200
    ON UPR00102.EMPLOYID = SY01200.Master_ID AND UPR00102.ADRSCODE = SY01200.ADRSCODE
WHERE UPR30300.PAYROLCD in (@Paycodes)or UPR30300.PAYROLCD in (@Benefits)or UPR30300.PAYROLCD in (@Deductions) and UPR30300.chekdate between (@Begindate) and (@Enddate)
```

Thanks!
Mike

Comment: Perhaps `WHERE ( ... OR... OR ...) AND ...`?

Comment: There are two problems: `in` is of lower priority than `and`, so it will be applied after all `ands` and probably bring more rows than expected; the other problem is using `in` with variable. If variable contains a list, which is to be expected by naming, you should use dynamic sql, or, in case you use Sql Server 2016, subquery with STRING_SPLIT function to transform the list to single-column table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ORs and INs and AND messed up the where clause. try below.

```
WHERE 
  UPR30300.PAYROLCD in (@Paycodes,@Benefits,@Deductions) 
  and UPR30300.chekdate between (@Begindate) and (@Enddate)
```

Answer (score 0):

combine the three in's into one in

WHERE UPR30300.PAYROLCD in (@Paycodes, @Benefits, @Deductions) and UPR30300.chekdate between (@Begindate) and (@Enddate)

or use brackets around the in's

WHERE (UPR30300.PAYROLCD in (@Paycodes)or UPR30300.PAYROLCD in (@Benefits)or UPR30300.PAYROLCD in (@Deductions)) and UPR30300.chekdate between (@Begindate) and (@Enddate)